# can you toggle sprint on BF3 on pc

Tags: pc, battlefield-3, controllers

I currently play battlefield 3 on the PC though have played it on the Xbox 360 where you can toggle the sprint when the left thumb stick is pressed down, and you will sprint until you stop moving forward. On the PC version if you want to sprint with the controller you have to hold down the thumb stick until you want to stop running, as this is starting to cause wear on my controller I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to make this toggle.

Thanks

Comment: Just to keep this post from withering. Ill get on this when i get home in a few hours.

Comment: I don't play PC shooting games with a controller(and I wonder why do you do it), but when you play with a keyboard and mouse you can press `W` + `Shift`(or another button that is sprint for you) and then release `W` and only hold `Shift`. You will sprint as long as you hold `Shift`

Comment: I find it much easier paying with a controller, it all comes down to the my preference and unfortunately that wouldn't work in the same way on the controller as if I did it that way I would still have to be pressing down on the directional stick which is something I would like to avoid

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. It was actually said at one point that you can walk but it has been removed due to people not being able to switch easily.